# Azure Diagnostic - how to get performance counter raw data

Tags: azure

i am looking for a way to get the raw data from a performance counter in windows azure

using the diagnostic api.

so far I've noticed that i can configured a counter from the known counters

and set the sampling rate for that counter.

Is the sampling rate configured in the diagnostics configuration is the sampling rate

that the counter calculation is based on ?

if not how can i get the raw data for that counter, since i want to get the cpu user time (for example)

and do the calculation by myself.

thanks

Comment: which counter are you specifically trying to use?

Answer (score 1):

Each counter has a sampling frequency from 1 second whatever number.  Azure will sample each instance at the given rate and capture the values and store them inside each instance.  Furthermore, there is a setting that allows Azure to transfer these values from each instance onto storage account's WADPerformanceCountersTable.  The transfer setting is measured in minutes and a minimum of once per minute.

To get details you want to read this:
http://convective.wordpress.com/2009/12/10/diagnostics-management-in-windows-azure/
and this:
http://convective.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/configuration-changes-to-windows-azure-diagnostics-in-azure-sdk-v1-3/

Comment: I am looking for the RAW value of a counter instead of the FORMATTED one. For example:
Sampling the Processor %User time by collecting the CPU time each interval (e.g.: 60 seconds) and calculate the percentage ourselves by dividing the CPU time in the time interval.
As I understand, the values I get are formatted and relate to the last second. 
I am familiar with the ability to ask for RAW values when using Dot-Net Diagnostic APIs but not via the Azure Diagnostics lib.
Is there a way to get RAW data via the Azure Diagnostics lib?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "formatted" values.  WADPerformanceCountersTable does not contain averages or aggregates of any sort, but true values (say CPU usages) as they were at the time sampled.  Also, Azure supports capturing any sort of performance counters, so if you were capturing values for a certain perf. counter on a regular Windows machine, chances are it exists on Azure machines.

Comment: If the perf-counter selection does not meet your needs, you may want to write your own library to capture counter values in a format you need.