# How can I monitor web hits on my Azure role

Tags: azure

I've been working on a web application and finally published it to Azure. The application is not critical and currently I use only one role to keep costs down.

I would like to start try and get a feel of who (if anyone is using my site). Can anyone give me some suggestions on how I could do this. What I would really like is not to use anything like the google scripts that I see some web sites use for monitoring page hits. I would like to do as much as possible on the server.

Help advice on where to start and what to look at would be much appreciated.

Katarina

Answer (score 2):

Aside from things like Google Analytics and StatCounter, you'd want to set up some performance counters that you can watch externally. This requires you to use the Diagnostic Monitor:

- Set up performance counters to track, and how often to poll for values
- Set up frequency to upload to Table Storage

Diagnostic data is aggregated from all your instances, so then you can run queries against the diagnostic tables. Cerebrata has a [page](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/AzureDiagnosticsManager/GettingStarted.aspx) that details these table names (you can also use their Diagnostics Manager tool, other 3rd-party tools, or roll your own).

Igork posted this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069076/azure-diagnostic-how-to-get-performance-counter-raw-data) as well, which references some blog posts by Azure MVP Neil Mackenzie.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Dave's answer, there are three levels of monitoring you can do:

If you want to know who is using your site, Google Analytics is best and free... There are a few others, but all involve injecting small javascript on your pages

If you want to know the **load** your site is under, inspecting performance counters via Cerebrata's tool is likely best @ http://www.cerebrata.com

If you want to go one step further and be notified when the load on your site is outside your predefined conditions (active monitoring) or have your website automatically scale up when the load is too high, AzureWatch is probably the best option @ http://www.paraleap.com

HTH